# Communicating with Drupal from Javascript/Jquery (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, javascript, entities

I am trying to create a dynamically populated select list field widget.  This widget consists of three Jquery multiple selects.  When the user makes a selection from the first select list I need to dynamically populate the contents of the second select list.  My problem is that I need to access data stored in Drupal about what should be put in the second list based on the first selection and the only way I can think to access this data is through an ajax call to a Drupal endpoint.  Waiting for the return from an ajax call is going to be to slow for a useable widget so I need a better way to access this data stored in Drupal.  How should one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send variables to your JS with [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in the $settings array.

An other way (the dirty one) to do it would be to *print* your data in a hidden div and read it with your JS. (don't hesitate to ask if you need code to do it)

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of ways to do that:

The drupal way would probably be to read a bit on chaos tools and fork the example for the dependent select box.

What I personally use is the great module knows as Views_datasource, that allows you to output view content as a json array.

So the workflow goes like this:

You have the first populated select, that you bind its change event. 
You retrieve the value of the select box and submit it via ajax to a view with a contextual filter rendered through views_datasource. 
You retrieve the json reply and populate you second select.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your code/module

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('awesome_cms' => 'Drupal-Seven')), 'setting');
```

Then from your jquery access `Drupal.settings.awesome_cms` to get the value `Drupal-Seven`